# substitute javascript variable in php code where the php code is inside a javascript code block

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, magento

I have a JS code. And in this i have a Js var and php code.
My code is like this :

```
<script  type="text/javascript">
var variablejs = 'toto';
var OptionsModel = '<?php $modeles = Mage::getModel('modeles/modele')->getCollection()->addfilter(marque, '+ variablejs + ');?><option><?php echo $this->__('Choose an Option...') ?></option><?php foreach ($modeles as $modele) : ?><option  val=\'<?php echo $modele->getMarque(); ?>\'><?php echo $modele->getModele(); ?></option><?php endforeach; ?>';
jQuery('#model').empty().append(OptionsModel);
</script>
```

Unfortunatelly, variablejs is called like text, not with 'toto' value.

Answer (score 2):

You need to `echo` that value. Right now your code is equivalent of

```
<?php

1
```

which is basically a no-op. It doesn't DO anything.

Try

```
var OptionsModel = <?php echo json_encode(Mage::GetModel(etc....)) ?>;
```

instead. Note the usage of json_encode(). This is a safety measure to ensure that whatever you're getting back from Magento is converted into syntactically valid Javascript. This basically prevents the JS equivalent of sql injection attacks

Comment: But without the jsvar, my code is working. My only problem is to call the jsvar...

Answer (score 0):

That will never work. You can only pass js variables to PHP through ajax calls. So make an ajax call to one of your controllers, and just return the options you need as a json. Then you can work with them on your js script.

Comment: Do you have an example? Thanks !

Comment: Is it possible for example with a session var? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This might help.

```
var OptionsModel = "@<?php $modeles = Mage::getModel('modeles/modele')->getCollection()->addfilter(marque, ";
    OptionsModel += variablejs;
    OptionsModel += "@);?><option><?php echo $this->__('Choose an Option...') ?></option><?php foreach ($modeles as $modele) : ?><option  val=\'<?php echo $modele->getMarque(); ?>\'><?php echo $modele->getModele(); ?></option><?php endforeach; ?>";
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell PHP what is in variablejs before the javascript is written to the page.
If variablejs gets set in Javascript AJAX is your answer. OptionsModel will have to be created based on the return from an AJAX call.